# unresolved external symbol with classes in my dll

Tags: c++, class, linker, abstract-class, linker-errors

I am trying to make a detection app using OpenCV and CMake. I made an abstract Detector class with two derived classes. When I use anything class-related in main.cpp I get linker error for that method, whether it's a constructor or a regular method.

The solution has an executable and two dll's. The problematic class is in one of the dll's.

> unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl FaceDetector::FaceDetector(struct detectorProperties)" (??0FaceDetector@@QEAA@UdetectorProperties@@@Z) referenced in function main

**ObjectDetection.h**

```c
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifdef OBJECTDETECTION_EXPORTS
#define OBJECTDETECTION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OBJECTDETECTION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern OBJECTDETECTION_API void drawLabel(cv::Mat & image, std::string label, int left, int top);

extern OBJECTDETECTION_API struct detectorProperties {
    // some variables
};

extern OBJECTDETECTION_API class Detector {
protected:
    std::string modelPath;
    bool shouldSwapRB = false;
    bool active = false;
    bool shouldDrawRect = true;

public:
    virtual void detect(cv::Mat& image) = 0;
};

extern OBJECTDETECTION_API class FaceDetector : public Detector {
private:
    cv::CascadeClassifier cs;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> facesInFrame;
public:
    FaceDetector(detectorProperties props);
    void detect(cv::Mat& image);

};
```

**ObjectDetection.cpp**

```
#include "ObjectDetection.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;

void drawLabel(cv::Mat & image, string label, int left, int top) {
    // function code
}

FaceDetector::FaceDetector(detectorProperties props) {
    // constructor code
}

// code
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ObjectDetection.h"

int main() {
    detectorProperties props;
    props.modelPath = "some/path";

    FaceDetector det = FaceDetector(props);
```

I can create instances of the struct and call `drawLabel`, but the class does not work.

**CMake output**

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22623.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32216.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32216.1
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
OpenCV ARCH: x64
OpenCV RUNTIME: vc16
OpenCV STATIC: OFF
Found OpenCV 4.7.0 in C:/OpenCV/build/x64/vc16/lib
You might need to add C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc16\bin to your PATH to be able to run your applications.
Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Configuring done (4.5s)
Generating done (0.2s)
```

**Top-level CMake file**

```
    # Qt 6.2.4 uses CMake 3.16, so that should be our minimum CMake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# Set the name for the project
project(DetectionApp)

# Specify where should the executables and libraries created
# This helps us avoid copying the files manually or using a post-build command
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMALE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{Qt6_DIR})

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS ${CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS} src/Application)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Gui Core Widgets)

# Add the subdirectories for the different parts of the application
add_subdirectory(src/Application)
add_subdirectory(src/CameraInteraction)
add_subdirectory(src/ObjectDetection)

add_subdirectory(src/CameraInteraction_v2)
add_subdirectory(src/ObjectDetection_v2)
add_subdirectory(src/WebCam)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

**Application CMake file**

```
# Set the project name
project(Application)

# Add the executable
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB UI_FILES "*.ui")
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "*.h")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${UI_FILES})

# Add the libraries
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    CameraInteraction
    ObjectDetection
)

# Allow the headers to be included in main.cpp
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                          "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/CameraInteraction"
                          "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ObjectDetection"
                           ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                          )
                    
#Link this project with te runtime output dir
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    CameraInteraction
    ObjectDetection
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Widgets
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
    MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
)
```

**library CMake file**

```
# Set the project name
project(ObjectDetection)

# Take every header and source in the directory
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp")

# Add the library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Link against OpenCV
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Evem if I create a simple class like:

```
class Test {
public:
  Test() {}
}
```

I still can't initialize it in main.

Comment: Please show the exact command line command and arguments you use to compile and link this project. You should be able to get them by turning `CMake` into verbose mode and extracting them from that output.

Comment: You have to be very explicit with a question like this or it'll be insta-closed as a duplicate of a massive omnibus Q&A that covers just about every different way you can get an undefined reference and not be told which of the hundred-or-so answers covers your specific case.

Comment: The only reason I didn't close the question as a duplicate is for the very reason @user4581301 mentioned. The duplicate you'll end up with be **extremely** verbose because it covers every kind of linking mistake made since the Big Bang. By being explicit, you'll hopefully save yourself from reading about all of them.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about the command line and arguments

Comment: @FeriCarnu The _"command line and arguments"_ are those that `cmake` actually issues to compile your source code and link your program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added the output. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is `extern OBJECTDETECTION_API class FaceDetector : public Detector {` correct? I have made many dlls in my career and never did it this way. I would expect it to be `class OBJECTDETECTION_API FaceDetector : public Detector {` instead and no `extern`

Comment: @drescherjm hmm... I changed it to what you said everywhere and for each item I get a linker error now

Comment: Did you define the preprocessor symbol:  `OBJECTDETECTION_EXPORTS` when building the dll an not when building the application, I don't see that in your CMakelists.txt. It should be a private [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html)

Comment: _" I added the output. Is that what you meant?"_ - No. I meant those few commands needed to replicate the problem. The CMake output you've shown is void of such information. I recommend learning how to compile and link manually at this stage since you've clearly passed the IDE "click/run" stage.

Comment: Note that using `GLOB` in CMake is an anti-pattern. You will need to re-run cmake explicitly every time you add a file, since your build system has no clue the new files exist. That may very well explain why your `ObjectDetection.cpp` is not being compiled. As a trivial test to see if you suffer from this, add an `#error` directive to ObjectDetection.cpp and recompile. I expect you will not see the error.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm a bit late, I forgot to update this post. Thank you! that's what solved my problem.